# Use monotonically_increasing_id() to create an incremental, but by a group of values from another column in pysaprk dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark

So I got an input pysaprk dataframe that looks like the following:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [("1111", "clark"),
     ("1111", "john"),
     ("2222", "bob"),
     ("3333", "jane"),
     ("3333", "lucie"),
     ("3333", "matt")    
    ],
    ["column1", "column2"]
)
```

```
| column1 | column2 |
| ------- | ------- |
| 1111    | clark   |
| 1111    | john    |
| 2222    | bob     |
| 3333    | jane    |
| 3333    | lucie   |
| 3333    | matt    |
```

And my goal is to create an incremental id, but that will increment per group of value from the `column1` in this case. So I get something like:

```
df_out = spark.createDataFrame(
    [("1111", "clark", 1),
     ("1111", "john", 2),
     ("2222", "bob", 1),
     ("3333", "jane", 1),
     ("3333", "lucie", 2),
     ("3333", "matt", 3)    
    ],
    ["column1", "column2", "incremental_id"]
)
```

```
| column1 | column2 | incremental_id |
| ------- | ------- | -------------- |
| 1111    | clark   | 1              |
| 1111    | john    | 2              |
| 2222    | bob     | 1              |
| 3333    | jane    | 1              |
| 3333    | lucie   | 2              |
| 3333    | matt    | 3              |
```

I tried using the window function as follow, but didn't get me the incremental_id values as I was hoping for per group of values from the `column1` column.

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number

w = Window().orderBy("column1")
df_out = df.withColumn("incremental_id", row_number().over(w))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing missing from your code is to specify the partition columns. In your example, it would look something like

```
w = Window.partitionBy('column2').orderBy("column1")
```

Everything else looks fine!